# Is it possible to use VS2010 on a VS2008 Solution w/o upgrading?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm working on a small team project, and would like to play around with VS2010 without forcing the entire team to. I would be fine maintaining 2 project files if there was some sort of script or app to help do so.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect not.

Based on history (never been possible before) and checking out a couple of solution files, one from 2008:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
```

and one from 2010:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 10
```

this seems likely to continue. The project files also contain a version, so you can't just use a different solution with the same projects.

On the other hand, VS2010 will support .NET 2, 3, 3.5 and 4.0, so you can upgrade VS without changing the target environment.